# How to use lambda function to print a pair<>?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I want to print a pair, e.g.

```
std::cout << make_pair(std::string,int) << endl;
```

But it doesn't compile because `operator<<(ostream &, std::pair<std::string,int>)` is not defined.

But because we now have c++11 with lambda functions, I can use lambda functions with a `for_each` expression to work on containers.

For the above case how could I supply an "in-place method" which can be used by ostream to print the pair?

Comment: *"which can be used by ostream"* What do you mean with *used by ostream*? Do you want to declare a function `ostream& operator<<(ostream&, pair<string,int> const&);`?

Comment: yes, i want to define the function, but 'in-place' not explicit

Comment: Well you cannot overload an operator by using a function that has no name. The only lambda I can think of that could be useful here is something like: `auto output_pair = [](ostream& o, pair<string,int> const& p) { o << p.first << p.second; }; output_pair(std::cout, my_first_pair); output_pair( std::cout, make_pair(my_string, my_int) );` (had a typo)

Answer (score 1):

Pairs (and other tuples) aren't really like containers, because their elements have heterogeneous types. They can't be iterated over in the normal way. So a lambda isn't really applicable here.

If you want, just define an `output_pair` template function which takes an ostream and a pair, and outputs the two elements of the pair. Or if you wanted to keep the extraction style, you could have `output_pair` return an `output_pair_struct` which does nothing but hold a copy of the tuple, and define an operator<< on the `output_pair_struct` which did the actual work, so that you could have `std::cout << output_pair(mypair) << endl;`.

Comment: i said lambda because it can be created in-place. similarly i wanted to create the `pair printing function` where i create the pair. and use it immediately in `cout`

Comment: There's no reason to create a lambda if you only intend to call it once, and right there. `std::cout << pair.first << pair.second`... what drawbacks does that line of code have that you are trying to address?

Comment: you are right, it can be done this way. but may be what i am trying to do here is simply to scratch an intellectual itch :) sometimes one does need to.

Comment: Square peg, round hole. If you're intellectually itchy, write a version of `for_each` which takes a `std::tuple` and a templated functor.

Answer (score 0):

> For the above case how could I supply an "in-place method" which can be used by ostream to print the pair?

```
auto print = [&](const std::pair<std::string,int>& p) {
    std::cout << p.first << ", " << p.second << "\n";
};

std::map<std::string,int> sequence = { /* ... */ };
for_each(sequence.begin(), sequence.end(), print);
for(const auto& p: sequence)
    print(p);
```

or:

```
for_each(sequence.begin(), sequence.end(),
    [&](const std::pair<std::string,int>& p) {
        std::cout << p.first << ", " << p.second << "\n";
});
```

Either way, this is too complicated. You should write it like this:

```
for(const auto& p: sequence)
    std::cout << p.first << ", " << p.second << "\n";
```